# Weird iterator behaviour + segfault with unordered_set

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-set

I have a class that has an `unordered_set<int>` member as follows:

I have the following class definition followed by its regular & copy constructors, as well as some other function that modifies the set (deleted irrelevant code segments since the class is very long):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <random>

class HexBoard {
  public:
    HexBoard(int n);
    HexBoard(const HexBoard &obj);
    std::unordered_set<int> emptyPositions();
  private:
    std::unordered_set<int> empty_positions;
};

HexBoard::HexBoard(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {
        empty_positions.insert(i);
    }
}

HexBoard::HexBoard(const HexBoard &obj) : empty_positions(obj.empty_positions) {};

void HexBoard::placeStone(int i) {
    checkBounds(i); // raises an error if i >= n 
    empty_positions.erase(i);
}

std::unordered_set<int> HexBoard::emptyPositions() {
    return empty_positions;
}
```

I have a different class that contains an instance of this HexBoard. It has a function that will copy that board into a different variable using the copy constructor:

```
class Game {
  public:
    Game(HexBoard::HexBoard *board) : board(board) {};
  private:
    HexBoard *board;
    void monteCarlo(int position);
};

void Game::monteCarlo(int position) {

    HexBoard *another_board = new HexBoard(*board);

    int count = 0;
    while (count < 5) {
        count++;

        std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> dis(
            0, another_board->emptyPositions().size() - 1
        );

        std::cout << "Empty positons:\n";
        for (const auto& pos : another_board->emptyPositions()) {
            std::cout << pos << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";

        int n = dis(gen);
        std::cout << "Picked random n: " << n << "\n";

        auto it = another_board->emptyPositions().begin();
        std::cout << "it begin: " << *it << "\n";
        std::advance(it, n);
        std::cout << "it advance: " << *it << "\n";
        int absolute_position = *it;
        std::cout << "picked " << absolute_position << "\n";
    }
}
```

In the `monteCarlo` function, let's say the contents of `emptyPositions` set were initially `8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1`, the stdout output of this function is usually:

```
Empty positons:
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
Picked random n: 4
it begin: 2
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Why does this segfault? I understand that there is some iterator subtly with regards to the `empty_positions.erase(i);` line, but even when I comment this out, I get the same behaviour.

I've also added this right after the `Picked random n` stdout and this segfaults as well (output below it):

```
std::cout << "set buckets contain:\n";
for ( unsigned i = 0; i < ai_board->emptyPositions().bucket_count(); ++i) {
    std::cout << "bucket #" << i << " contains:";
    for ( auto j = ai_board->emptyPositions().begin(i);
          j != ai_board->emptyPositions().end(i); ++j)
        std::cout << " " << *j;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
set buckets contain:
Segmentation fault: 11
```

The segfault happens at `std::advance(it, n);` and at this last manual iteration.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you located the crash with a debugger? Where does it happen? Do you have a null-pointer or another pointing looking uninitialized or possibly a pointer to an out-of-scope object?

Comment: It happens at `std::advance(it, n);` and the last segment that I have where I tried to do manual iteration. No nothing is out of scope there are no pointers if you re-read this. Just iterators controlled by c++ iterator functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `HexBoard` class you have:

```
std::unordered_set<int> emptyPositions();
```

That is, the function returns a set *by value*.

Then you later do

```
auto it = another_board->emptyPositions().begin();
```

That will cause `emptyPositions` to return a ***temporary*** object, one that will be destructed once the expression is finished. That will leave you with an iterator to a key in a now destructed set. Dereferencing this iterator will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The solution is to make the `emptyPositions` return a constant reference instead:

```
std::unordered_set<int> const& emptyPositions() const;
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem is that `emptyPositions()` is returning a copy of the `unordered_set`. As a result, `another_board->emptyPositions().begin()` returns an iterator from a temporary whose lifetime is not guaranteed. It is probably being cleaned up before you iterate through it.

You probably meant to have `emptyPositions()` return a reference to the state variable `empty_positions`.